# How to delete sideborder using templates

Tags: html, templates, border

on my website i want to remove the standart border which is around the whole website, with this CSS I managed to do this:

```
body {
    margin: 0; 
}
```

The thing is, in my index page, which doesnt use a template this works perfectly fine, but in all my other pages i use a template, which does refer to the same CSS Stylesheed file as the index, but strangly enough it doesn`t work there, the border is still there.
Somebody knows how to fix this?

Here some picture of what i mean:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/bJTFF.png]

Comment: set position to absolute and set top to 0 or -5px...

Comment: I wish comments could be -1'd.

Comment: sry but doesnt work, absolute position breaks the complete layout

Comment: have you tried adding `padding:0px;`?